# Why does including a "significant" (p-value <0.05) effect increase AIC in GAM?

Tags: mixed-model, aic, generalized-additive-model

I am using the mgcv package in R to model population trends of edible dormice in several sites over 14 years. I used Plot_ID as a random effect, year as a fixed effect and the number of boxes controlled (which is where dormice where counted) as an offset. Since data were slightly overdispersed, I used the negative binomial family.
The model output looks like this:

```
Family: Negative Binomial(1.729) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
Adult ~ offset(log(Boxes)) + s(Plot_ID, bs = "re") + s(Year)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -3.4431     0.1294  -26.61   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
              edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(Plot_ID) 39.789     49  274.1  <2e-16 ***
s(Year)     1.704      9   11.9  0.0763 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.304   Deviance explained = 37.9%
-REML =   1083  Scale est. = 1         n = 544
```

Then, I decided to include presence of dormice on the site in the year before as an additional variable, to see whether this was important. Presence_yearbefore is the number of dormice divided by the number of boxes controlled, so if there were 5 dormice in 50 boxes in 2011, presence_yearbefore is 0.1 in 2012).
In model1, I excluded all years where presence_yearbefore was NA (so all the first years on each plot and some years in between when counting hasn't been done every year), so I use exactly the same dataset as in model2.
This resulted in the following model:

```
Family: Negative Binomial(1.73) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
Adult ~ offset(log(Boxes)) + s(Plot_ID, bs = "re") + s(Presence_yearbefore) + 
    s(Year)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -3.4305     0.1175   -29.2   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                          edf Ref.df  Chi.sq p-value    
s(Plot_ID)             37.996     49 149.200  <2e-16 ***
s(Presence_yearbefore)  1.988      9  33.796  0.0258 *  
s(Year)                 1.490      9   7.806  0.0943 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.326   Deviance explained = 37.8%
-REML = 1081.1  Scale est. = 1         n = 544
```

From the output it seems like "Presence_yearbefore" is "significant" (p-value < 0.05). But then, why is the AIC lower in the first model?

```
> AIC(model1, model2)
             df      AIC
model1 44.97548 2117.164
model2 46.18304 2121.214
```

I know it's not a huge difference, but I would have expected the AIC to decrease when including predictor with a low p-value. Could this have something to do with my random effect? I noticed that chi squared for Plot ID is a lot lower in the second model.
Should I include Presence_yearbefore even though it increases the AIC?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How do you define "significant" and how would the situation change if you changed your definition ?

Comment: My definition of significant was based on the p-values. As I understand it, the p-values of the smooth terms in a gam test whether the smoothing function is significantly different from a function which is constantly zero. Thus, I thought if they are for a given predictor, this predictor should be related to my response.

Comment: Your question made me think and I guess I could also define significant predictors based on the deviance explained (as this takes account of the offset in contrary to the adjusted R squared). Then, this leads me to the conclusion that the first model is slightly better than the second one. Is this a better way to find out whether predictors are significant?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "significant" ? You mentioned p values and those are the probabilities of observing these data or data more extreme is the real associatio is zero.

Comment: I defined p-values of 0.05 or below as "significant". But even if I changed that to a lower value and "count_yearbefore" wasn't "significant" any more according to this new definition, isn´t the p-value of 0.0258 (the probability of observing this or more extreme data when the real association is 0) still quite low?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "quite low". The problem with arbitrary definitions of "significance" is that according to your suggestion 0.049999 would be significant, whereas 0.0500001 would not

Comment: You're right. I will edit the question that it becomes clear what I mean by significant and keep in mind that this definition is very arbitrary. Thank you for your thougths on this!

Answer (score 0):

You added a "significant" term to the model (in the sense that the test against a null hypothesis of a flat function yields a p value < 0.05) but you made the $f(\text{Year})$ term less useful than it was before — likely because some of the variation $f(\text{Year})$ was capturing in the first model is now taken up by $f(\text{Presence_yearbefore})$.

AIC is not the only arbiter of model success; it is focused on prediction and all else equal is saying that predicting from the second model will yield somewhat more poor *predictions*. If you're interested in something other than predicting, maybe don't put so much weight on what the AIC is telling you.

That said, from what I understand about your model, you now have two terms that are temporally related:

1. $f(\text{Year})$ is a smoothly varying trend, and
2. $f(\text{Presence_yearbefore})$

Depending on how much data you have, consider if the basis size for $f(\text{Year})$ is sufficient (via `gam.check()`)

Also, what is `Presence_yearbefore`? It sounds like a binary variable and if so, I'm not sure what you hope to achieve by smoothing a 0/1 variable?

I'm not convinced by the removal of the years with zero observed individuals; a 0 is a valid count so why not include these years?

Comment: Dear Gavin Simpson, thank you for your answer! Presence_year before is not binary; it's the number of dormice found divided by the number of boxes controlled on each plot at year-1 (so if there were 5 dormice in 50 boxes in 2011, presence_yearbefore is 0.1 in 2012). That´s also what I meant by "excluding years with no count the previous year" - I mean all the years where dormice haven't been counted in the previous year, so all the first years and some years in between when counting hasn´t been done every year. I´m sorry that I wasn't clear, I will edit my question!

Comment: I'm not interested in predictions, what I want to know is "what's the temporal trend" ( I did this via the first model with only year) and "what affects number of dormice on each site". In the second model, I also included weather data such as "winter temperature", but with the weather variables, low p-values gave lower AIC, which is why I was confused about presence_yearbefore. Can I say that in my data, number of dormice counted were influenced by the number of dormice which were counted on the plot in the previous year?